# How to do you find which site in Stack Exchange is highly active?

Tags: support, statistics, traffic

Is there way I can find out which Stack Exchange site/s is highly active (some statistics) at the current moment?

**Definition of active**:

1. More people are online and are browsing Stack Exchange sites.
2. Answering.
3. Asking questions.
4. Reviewing.
5. Upvoting.
6. Down voting.
7. Involved in chat.
8. etc.

Comment: Well I'd imagine Stack Overflow is the most active at any point in time…

Comment: Is there a place you could go(visit) and get statistics?

Comment: Is this discussion, support, or a feature request?

Answer (score 6):

Some of the stats are available at https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic where you can sort all sites based on the following criteria:

- Traffic
- Oldest
- Newest
- Questions
- Answers
- Percent Answered
- Users
- Questions Per Day
- Name

Answer (score 3):

You can approximate this behavior by fiddling with the Stack Exchange API

For instance, [this query](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/posts?page=1&pagesize=100&fromdate=1380240000&todate=1380326400&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=!FSKNZa0lf3yDQ) will return the number of posts from 9-27 to 9-28 (today).

Now you can fiddle around with this query by fiddling with the date amounts. For instance:

`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/posts?page=1&pagesize=100&fromdate=1380240000&todate=1380326400&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=!FSKNZa0lf3yDQ`

You can change the `fromdate` (which is in [UNIX Epoch Time](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/dates)) to something better (last hour, last 6 hours, whatever).

The issue is that API calls are heavily cached so they may not be up to date (my query to show all posts from the last 30 minutes returned a zero), and using the API in this way may be considered abusive under the [terms of service](https://stackexchange.com/legal/api-terms-of-use) depending on how and how often you use it.

I think the bigger question is why on earth would you want that information?